# Can i use subquery instead of joining a table?

Tags: sql, join, subquery, left-join

My table schema looks something like this :

[image: Schema screenshot]

The question I am trying to solve: Give all the customers that live in the city "Irvine", but only we want to list stores for "Newport".

The subquery that I have tried writing is as follows:

```
select distinct c.customer_number, c.store_number
from customer c 
  left join invoice i on c.customer_number = i.customer_number
where customer_city = "Irvine" 
  and store_number IN (select store_number 
                       from store 
                       where store_city = "Newport")
```

I am using a left join since I also need to include customers who have signed up, not just the ones that have an invoice, my confusion is, is using a subquery, in this case, valid? or should I have used another join instead?

Can someone please explain me the logic so that my concept of joins become clearer

Comment: If there are more than 1 store than you have to use `IN` operator. Alternatively, you can use the `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: in SQL string constants should be specified with single quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers. `"Irvine"` is a column name in your query, `'Irvine'` would be a string constant.

Comment: Why do you join to the `invoice` table at all? Your question does not involve a requirement like "only customers with an invoice". If you remove the join, you can get rid of the DISTINCT as well. If you do want customers with invoices only, use an `EXISTS` condition to avoid the join and thus the DISTINCT operator

Comment: As a note, `LEFT JOIN` is not appropriate.  You need an `invoice` record in order to have a `store_number`, so `JOIN` is appropriate.